# findChessboardCorners failing

Tags: camera-calibration, opencv, python

Im using the findChessboardCorners in Opencv using python and with over 50 samples none have been successfully detected. Sample: [FailedChessboardSample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWBAD.jpg) [FailedchessboardSample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jw1W.jpg)
I'm doing this to calibrate the camera.

code:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

images = glob.glob('Chessboards/*.jpg')
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6),None)
    cv2.imshow("img", gray)
    cv2.waitKey(100)
    print(ret)
    if ret == True:
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img,(7,6), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow(fname, img)
        cv2.waitKey()


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please add some code example

Comment: Try thresholding your image either as preprocessing or using the arguments for drawChessboardCorners. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga93efa9b0aa890de240ca32b11253dd4a